# Eclipse update problem?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6

Please take a look here:

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2810/errrp.jpg](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2810/errrp.jpg)

Why i got that error when i'm trying to update my Eclipse Galileo to the newest Eclipse M6 Helios?
I'm using the update URL from here:

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2010/03/14/eclipse-3-6-m6-helios-available-for-download/

Is this a bug? If not, what can i do?

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the upgrade process after re-launching eclipse with the `-clean` option?
Do you confirm you are using the **http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6milestones/** update site address?

What version of eclipse are you using (3.5, 3.5.1, 3.5.2?) and what extra plugin did you installed?

For instance, if you have installed Scala for Eclipse, you could not upgrade AspectJ which could block the upgrade process. (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg11220.html) for illustration)

---

To summarize the 3-days span and 15 comments below:

An easiest path to solve this would be:

- have a fresh installation of Eclipse, especially the [Java EE Helios package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/M6/eclipse-jee-helios-M6-win32.zip) (see [Helios packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/m6))
- with an [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) including a `-data /path/to/existing workspace`
  ( That way, you have 2 Eclipse referencing the same Eclipse projects. You can launch one or the other, and if the new one does not work, you can still revert to the old one. This is safer than trying modifying extensively -- through the update process -- your current Eclipse)
- add the  [GlassFish plugin for Eclipse](https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/download/index.html)
  (download both the plugin and feature jar files, quit Eclipse, then copy the unzipped contents of the first into the plugins directory and the second into the features directory of your Eclipse installation)
- Check you [Java EE JDK](http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/index.jsp) if needed

And here you go: you should be able to see a GlassFish Server and integrate it as a target runtime there.

Comment: And how can i launch Eclipse with -clean option?

Comment: And how can i see what version of Eclipse i'm using? i did not see in Help->About Eclipse

Comment: @qwerty: type "eclipse.exe -clean", and you can start by copy the build id seen in "About Eclipse". Then click on Installation details and search in the first tab (Installed Software)

Comment: So i have:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Build id: 20090920-1017
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2009.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://eclipse.org/

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation http://apache.org/

What i want is the latest Eclipse, M6 Helios. But i have already an Eclipse, so i wanna just update

Comment: @qwerty although you could consider a fresh eclipse Helios 3.6M6 installation (which can refer to the same workspace than your current eclipse, see this `eclipse.ini`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590): that way if the new Eclipse is not working well enough, you still have a current (and working) installation to fall back to.

Comment: Well i think i did not understand you here... so i should modify eclipse.ini, by modifying it like in that thread? My current workspace is C:\workspace

Comment: @qwerty: my point is: you can unzip a fresh Eclipse Helios somewhere else, and then modify its `eclipse.ini` in order to reference in that new `eclipse.ini` the path to your current workspace. That way, you have 2 Eclipse referencing the same Eclipse projects. You can launch one or the other, and if the new one does not work, you can still revert to the old one. This is safer than trying modifying extensively (through the update process) your current Eclipse.

Comment: OK, but in that thread you gave me, there isn't specified the path of the workspace. the thread is about best JVM settings for Eclipse. However, when i start Eclipse, it askes me for a workspace, so why i should configure eclipse.ini for this?

Comment: @qwerty: Because the thread I refer to *also* includes the path to the default workspace you want to use in the 2 first lines (`-data
../../workspace`). `eclipse.ini` is a good place to specify that path, in order to just launch eclipse and be sure to open the right set of projects.

Comment: And what should i download in order to make a new Java EE 6.0 project? I downloaded Eclipse M6 Helios but i don't see any Java EE capabilities

Comment: @qwerty Good question: you need to download an Eclipse Helios *package* (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/m6), specifically the Java EE one: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/M6/eclipse-jee-helios-M6-win32.zip

Comment: Thanks for reply. And if i create a new EJB Project, for example, there i cannot see any Glassfish Server... how can i integrate a glassfish server as a target runtime there?
Thanks

Comment: @qwerty: you need to add the server connector for Glassfish (see http://www.imixs.org/websites/imixs-org.nsf/chapter/3000.0020.0005.0510.?OpenDocument for illustration)

Comment: I followed those steps, and when i click 'download aditional server updates', i see nothing in that list. Why? Is it any other method to install glassfish server for Java EE6 into Eclipse M6 Helios?

Regards,

Comment: @qwerty: my guess is you need to download the "GlassFish tool Bundle" for Eclipse first, before clicking 'download additional server updates' and being able to see and select it. See https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/

Comment: but if i use Glassfish tool Bundle for Eclipse (i choose a new workspace, etc.), when i create a new EJB project, i can't select EJB 3.1 version. But this tool Bundle for Eclipse includes the Glassfish servers. On the other side, in Eclipse M6 Helios i don't have any Glassfish servers, but i have EJB 3.1 module version. What can i do? 
Thanks!

Comment: @qwerty: you are correct: the tool Bundle is not the right answer. Rather, take your fresh Helios installation, and add it the GlassFish plugin for Eclipse (from the same page https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/), download both the plugin and feature jar files, quit Eclipse, then copy the unzipped contents of the first into the plugins directory and the second into the features directory of your Eclipse installation. See: https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/download/index.html

Comment: And should i have installed Java EE 6 SDK? A link for download?

Regards,

Comment: @qwerty: glad to help. I have updated the answer to reflect the new process to work with GlassFish Server in a Eclipse Helios M6 IDE.

Comment: To install the GlassFish plugin via the Update Manager, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538433/how-to-install-the-glassfish-v3-server-adapter-with-eclipse-3-6m6-helios/2538445#2538445