# How to install the GlassFish 3 server adapter with Eclipse Helios 3.6

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3, eclipse-3.6

Question as stated in the title: how to install the GlassFish Server Adapter on Eclipse Helios 3.6?

Comment: The Glassfish adapter shows up in the Additional server adapters dialogue now.

Comment: To avoid confusion for 3.7 you may want to either make a note that for 3.7 Indigo the adapter should be downloaded from the marketplace, or simply delete this question?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Eclipse Helios 3.6

At the time of writing this (07/26/2010), there are in theory two ways to install the GlassFish Server adapter: via the Eclipse Marketplace or via an update site.

**Update:** As mentioned by [Thorbjørn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897) in a comment, the adapter is now (09/24/2010) available in the  Additional server adapters dialogue (the "normal way").

#### New Server

There are several ways to do this but one ways is to **right-click** in the **Server** view, select **New > Server** then click the **Download additional server adapters** link and select the GlassFish adapter.

#### Marketplace

Go to **Help > Eclipse Marketplace...** and search for *"glassfish"*. Then click on the **Install** button of the  [GlassFish Java EE Application Server Plugin for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-java-ee-application-server-plugin-eclipse?mpc=true&mpc_state=) and follow the steps.

[image]

#### Update site

Go to **Help → Install New Software**, **Add** the following temporary<sup>1</sup> update site: http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios. Be **sure** to uncheck **Group items by category** and you should see the **Oracle GlassFish Server Tools** as shown below:

[image]

Click on **Next** and follow the steps.

<sup>1</sup> The GlassFish plugin is being moved to the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE) and will be available at http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/helios/wtp in the future (see [Bug 312912](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312912)).

---

---

The problem mentioned above is actually **not** specific to the GlassFish plugin and is **not** platform specific. The issue is a p2 bug in Eclipse 3.6 when using a ***shared install*** (which is the root cause of the problem) as I discovered after reading this **[other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3398966)** on SO and the [Bug 322929](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322929). The problem is related to a p2 bug which is **fixed** in Eclipse 3.6 SR1 and after installing Eclipse 3.6 SR1 RC4, things are now indeed working as expected. Yeah!

Comment: Good summary. +1. I had done the information update on the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330770/where-to-download-glass-fish-plugins-for-eclipse-3-6-helios/3330942#3330942) before reading your own update. I have voted to close that other question as duplicate, hoping for a merge.

Comment: @VonC: Thanks. I have actually requested a merge, trying to centralize things (inspired by your awesome eclipse.ini answers).

Answer (score 13):

### Eclipse Helios 3.6 M6

With the Eclipse 3.6 M6 Java EE bundle, if you try to install the GlassFish v3 server adapter via the **New Server** dialog and then click on the **Download Additional server adapters**, Eclipse contacts remote sites but fail at showing any adapter:

[image]

This issue is actually captured by [Bug 305636](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305636). Using the Update Site instead of the New Server Wizard allows to workaround the issue:

1. Install a new [Eclipse Helios M6](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/m6) (get the *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers* package).
2. Install the latest GlassFish server adapter, today that is 1.0.52:

   1. Open **Help > Install New Software**
   2. Add the GlassFish update site URL: https://ajax.dev.java.net/eclipse
   3. Install the **GlassFish Java EE 5, Java EE 6** plugin
   4. Restart when prompted
3. Open the **New > Server** wizard and add your GlassFish v3 Java EE 6 server.

Comment: @Pascal: thank you, seems much easier that way. +1 all around.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more generic and cover all versions of Eclipse 3.6. Now that the final release of Eclipse Helios 3.6 is there, I'm unmarking this question as accepted.

Comment: Could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526861/java-applet-java-util-missingresourceexception

Answer (score 4):

I get the following when I try this:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: GlassFish Java EE 5, Java EE 6 1.0.54 (com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.feature.feature.group 1.0.54)
  Missing requirement: GlassFish Java EE 5, Java EE 6 1.0.54 (com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.feature.feature.group 1.0.54) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.5.0,3.6.0)' but it could not be found

Comment: Add oracle glassfish server tools from http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/helios/wtp
And restart it. you will be able to add glassfish as server to eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse Helios already have the correct source to download the glassfish plugin but, the site is **not available yet**. 
The site will be available at the end of july according to this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312912

You can use a development update site to install a rc version of the glassfish plugin for helios witch is:

**http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios**

**Add this** to your update sites and then uncheck the option "**Group items by category**" and you will see and be able to install the **Glassfish Plugin in Helios**

Answer (score 1):

The above URL did not work for me (I am using final release of Helios).

I had to do

`help` -> `eclipse market place` -> [`then select glassfish plugin from the 'search' tab`]

Answer (score 1):

**On the new Eclipse (JUNO):**

Help --> Install New Software...

Then, insert `http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno` inside the URL field, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.