# Getting GlassFish Adapter to Work in Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

Tags: glassfish, eclipse-3.6

I recently downloaded the Java EE+BIRT package of Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) for 32-bit Windows (Windows Vista, I know...) to give it a whirl. I am using this alongside the J2EE package of the JDK Sun provides, which of course includes GlassFish v3. This is a clean installation with the old .eclipse configuration directory and Eclipse workspace folder blown away.

It looks like the GlassFish Adapter was available via the Eclipse Marketplace, so I tried that. It mentioned something about unsigned content (appearing to have eclipse-3.5 in the file names), but I OK'd through that. On restart, the Installed Software panel shows the GlassFish Adapter to have been installed, but I cannot find GlassFish among the server runtime environments to add.

So I blew away everything again and tried installing the adapter per instructions found [on this blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/eclipse_3_6_helios_glassfish). I added the repository from the URL specified (http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios), unchecked the group by category option, and chose to install the adapter. Again, I got a warning about unsigned content but OK'd through it. On restart, again it shows the adapter as installed, but again I cannot find it as one of the server runtimes to use.

Anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: I posted about [GlassFish + Eclipse Helios M6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538433/how-to-install-the-glassfish-v3-server-adapter-with-eclipse-3-6m6-helios) some time ago but didn't retry or recheck since then. Still, you might want to check the related bug mentioned in an answer.

Comment: Ok, exact same problem here (under Linux). But no, I'm not going to install the plugin as root, I stick to Galileo for now.

Answer (score 0):

Pieter Agten wrote a reply on that blog saying he successfully installed the plug-in as root, and sure enough, I ran Eclipse as Administrator, and the plug-in successfully installed! Previously, I hadn't considered it necessary to run as Administrator to install plug-ins in Eclipse, but it looks like I was mistaken.