# Where to download GlassFish plugins for Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, glassfish

Would you please help me to download GlassFish plugins for Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).

I tried 'https://ajax.dev.java.net/eclipse' URL in new software install in the Eclipse, but it doesn't work and show me 'Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.' Error

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install the GlassFish v3 server adapter with Eclipse Helios 3.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538433/how-to-install-the-glassfish-v3-server-adapter-with-eclipse-helios-3-6)

Answer (score 3):

As of January 2011 the easiest way is to install it through the Eclipse Marketplace.

- Select "Eclipse Marketplace..." (found in the Help menu under Windows).
- Choose "Eclipse Marketplace" catalog
- On the Search pane enter "Glassfish" in the "Find" textbox.
- Locate "GlassFish Tools Bundle for Eclipse" (not the older plugin), and click the "Install" button.

The rest is just like a normal plugin installation.

---

The distribution is being changed. For now there is a new Update site. Full details in the official announcement:  http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/eclipse_3_6_helios_glassfish

> While for earlier versions of Eclipse developers had the choice of using the GlassFish Tools Bundle for Eclipse (an all-in-one bundle) or simply adding the GlassFish plugin using a pre-wired software site, it's a tiny bit more complicated for the time being with this 3.6/Helios release.
>   You'll need to:
>
> - add **`http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios`**  as a new software site (`preferences>install/update>Available Software Site`) and
> - install the plugin (`Help>Install New Plugin`) **while making sure that "Group Items by Category" is unchecked**.
>
> Real soon now this feature should be on the [Eclipse marketplace (check this out)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/oracle-enterprise-pack-eclipse) and in the longer term, the GlassFish plugin is being moved to the [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE)](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/oepe/index.html).
>   Finally, note that no matter how you get the plugin, it'll come with full Java EE (5 & 6) javadocs.
>   Feedback and bug reports should go to [glassfishplugins.dev.java.net](https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/).

---

From the [mailing list](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/servlets/ReadMsg?list=users&msgNo=47693), more confirmation:

> Well, first of all, the previous Update Site we used to host our plugin is maintained for the Eclipse 3.5 version. But it will not work with Eclipse 3.6.
>
> Our GlassFish plugin binary is being moved to the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse OEPE. This update site will be live in a few days...
>   Meanwhile, you can register the Update site for promoted builds of the GlassFish server adapter for Eclipse 3.6:

```
http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios
```

> **Make sure after you register this update site to Eclipse 3.6, you click on the check box called "Group Items by Category" to see the plugins**.
>   We offer now 3 plugins:

- 1 for the GlassFish Servers (2.x, 3.0, 3.0.1 and nightly 3.1)
- 1 for the Java EE 5 javadoc (available in the Java Editor code completion and the help menu)
- 1 for the Java EE 6 javadoc (available in the Java Editor code completion and the help menu).

> So you can either wait for the official release of Oracle OEPE (you can track it at 
>   http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/oracle-enterprise-pack-eclipse ), or use for now our developer/early access update site.

Comment: Good catch. +1. I have added the relevant information for archive (even if your link is no longer valid one day, its content will persist in this post on SO)

Comment: Your new link 'http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios' seems doesn't work. What happens guys?

Comment: @Navid, the easiest way to do it January 2011 is to install it from the Eclipse Marketplace.