# Eclipse 3.5+: Loading plug-ins from auto-created .eclipse directory inside user's home directory

Tags: linux, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, load

I have downloaded the latest Eclipse (3.6) for my Linux machine and extracted tar.gz to the /opt/eclipse directory as root. I started Eclipse as a normal user and successfully installed some plug-ins through Eclipse. The plug-ins are visible under "Installed software" from Eclipse, but they doesn't seem to be working - no new perspectives that should be there, no features, nothing. 
Then I looked inside my home folder and found the following directory:

.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_1473617060

That directory structure looks similar to the one in the /opt/eclipse (where Eclipse is installed) and has 4 directories inside ("dropins", "configuration", "plugins", "features") and one file ("artifacts.xml"). The "plugins" folder really containts all the plug-ins I have installed.

I have already read the following topic:
[Installing Eclipse (3.4+) plugins in a directory other than ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipse-home-plugins)
and tried to put .link file in "opt/eclipse/dropins" and/or "opt/eclipse/links" directory pointing to the configuration directory in my home directory, but that doesn't seem to be working.

So these are the steps to reproduce the problem, in short:

1. Run Eclipse as some user which has no write permissions to installation dir
2. Install plug-ins through Eclipse and restart it (as the same user)
3. Eclipse now shows that those plug-ins are installed. The plugins are indeed located somewhere in the home directory of the user who installed them (~/.eclipse/.../plugins).

Problem: plug-ins are somehow ignored.
I know that I can quick-fix the problem by copying the plugins manually to the installation directory (as a root) each time I install a plug-in as a non-root (or always install plug-ins as root), but I am interested in the way how can I configure Eclipse to read the user's own configuration file and plugins which have been automatically generated by Eclipse in the first place.

Any ideas how can I force Eclipse to actually use the plug-ins installed by Eclipse?

Comment: I was starting to think that I was the only one in the world suffering from this problem and this question is the only relevant link I could find so far. So thanks for the question **and** the bug link.

Comment: Problem solved after installing Eclipse 3.6 SR1 RC4, thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a p2 bug. Can you open a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Equinox)?

Comment: I reported it. Indeed, it seems it is a bug, here is the link:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322158