# eclipse servers

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have the Eclipse for Java EE Developers, and when I'm trying to create a new server runtime, I don't see in that list Apache Tomcat, or Glassfish v3 Prelude servers.
Where are they?
I tried to 'Download additional servers' but I see only 5 versions of Geronimo and a Jetty server, no apache and other Glassfish versions.

What update site should I use to integrate those additional servers into Eclipse?
Here I have the image:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538433/how-to-install-the-glassfish-3-server-adapter-with-eclipse-helios-3-6 help?

Comment: i tried all of the update sites from here but i still cannot find Glassfish v3 prelude server..

Answer (score 0):

> I tried all of the update sites from here but I still cannot find Glassfish v3 prelude server.

First, GlassFish 3 is out for some time now and I believe the update sites have been updated to reflect this (i.e. to don't offer an adapter for the *prelude* version). Second, since GlassFish 3 is out, why would you use the *prelude* version? Third, according to the screenshot of your question, you already have the adapter for GlassFish 3. If you insist with using *prelude*, did you try the GlassFish 3 adapter with it?

Comment: Thank you, but where is the apache server? why i did not have the apache servers?