# Install the GlassFish 3 server adapter with Eclipse Helios 3.6, I got a problem

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

When I install the GlassFish 3 server adapter with Eclipse Helios 3.6 SR1 by [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538433/how-to-install-the-glassfish-3-server-adapter-with-eclipse-helios-3-6/3086462#3086462)
(Take care the third answer, I got the same problem.)

I got the wrong message:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: GlassFish Java EE 5, Java EE 6 1.0.54 (com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.feature.feature.group 1.0.54)
  Missing requirement: GlassFish Java EE 5, Java EE 6 1.0.54 (com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.feature.feature.group 1.0.54) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.5.0,3.6.0)' but it could not be found

The main message is requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.5.0,3.6.0)', just like the third answer the way I followed.

Any suggestion ? Thank you.