# Indigo Java EE with GlassFish bundle

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I use Eclipse Indigo Java EE and I want to use the GlassFish 3 server. I am used to work with Tomcat which can easily be accessed from Eclipse.

I followed [How to install the GlassFish 3 server adapter with Eclipse Helios 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538433/how-to-install-the-glassfish-3-server-adapter-with-eclipse-helios-3-6) answer but I got the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: GlassFish Java EE 5, Java EE 6 1.0.54 (com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.feature.feature.group 1.0.54)
>     Missing requirement: GlassFish Java EE 5, Java EE 6 1.0.54 (com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.feature.feature.group 1.0.54) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.5.0,3.6.0)' but it could not be found

The solution for this problem is a dated link so I can't find any way to solve this issue.
Please provide me a up-to-date solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information in the linked question is outdated.

You should

- Download and unzip glassfish separately.
- In Eclipse, choose Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...,  and search for Glassfish.  This will locate amongst others "GlassFish Java EE Application Server Plugin for Eclipse" which has an Install button.  Use the button to install.
- Wait.
- Restart Eclipse if prompted.
- In the Servers view, right-click and choose New -> Server...  Now you can choose to install a Glassfish server.  Be certain to use exactly the adapter for the Glassfish server you have.  Point to the glassfish folder inside the unpacked server.

Comment: Thanks! It works great! One problem though.. I can't see any error info. It tells me that I need GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs. What is the correct way to add this over my current instals so I don't mess up any thing.

Comment: Did you choose the exact right adapter - it appears to be picky.  For 3.1.1 choose the 3.1.1 adapter, for 3.0.1 choose the one with the long name.

Comment: There are two GlassFish products but I'm allowed to install just the GlassFish Java EE Application Server Plugin for Eclipse. I'm using GlassFish 3.1.1