# Installing a new Glassfish server on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am trying to create a new Glassfish server instance in my Eclipse Indigo IDE. I have downloaded the additional server adapters. I select

`New -> Server -> GlassFish -> GlassFish 3.x`

and click on Next. But nothing happends.

Is this a bug and if so, what's the workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Maybe you did something wrong when you installed the additional server adapters or you have chosen the wrong one? Because my working setup doesn't let me choose `GlassFish 3.x` but a specific version like `GlassFish 3.1` or `GlassFish 3.1.1`.

You have to install the `Glassfish Server Tools for Indigo` from the Eclipse Marketplace (Help -> Eclipse Marketplace).

After restarting Eclipse you can do it like you described:

```
New -> Server -> GlassFish -> your specific Glassfish version
```

After clicking next you can choose the server directory and the JDK (you need a JDK to run Glassfish).

If this doesn't help you may try the same with a clean installation of Eclipse.

Anyway Eclipse Indigo is pretty old, you should upgrade to a recent version.

**See also:**

- [Indigo Java EE with GlassFish bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046803/indigo-java-ee-with-glassfish-bundle)

Comment: Hey man. Appreciate your answer. I might have been a bit misleading, with 3.x i ment that I had a group of version to chose from. For example, 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3. I will try your recommendation to install it from the marketplace in a while. Thanks again.

Comment: As I suspected it just gives me this feedback: "Nothing to update" 
I installed the server tools via the "install new software" wizard, so I guess it's just saying that it's the same version that I already have.

Comment: Maybe you can try again with a clean Eclipse installation.

Comment: I probably wont since I have so much configuration and work on my current installation... Also I can configure and deploy to the server in my browser via the admin console. Appreciate your efforts but as I said reinstalling is kind of a last resort :p

Comment: Then uninstalling the server adapters and reinstalling it via the Marketplace may be an option.

Comment: Go to `Install new software` and click on `What is already installed`.

Comment: Tried it. Same bug. This is some really wierd shit going on right here.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this problem, while clicking Next button nothing happens.

I noticed on the Error log panel, that a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` has been thrown:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.SapphirePropertyEditorCondition cannot be found by com.liferay.ide.eclipse.portlet.ui_1.6.2.v201303111029
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 108 more
```

,that is there has to be something wrong with my earlier installed Liferay plugin.

I thought Liferay plugin update can solve this issue, however it was up-to-date. Since I don't need that plugin currently, uninstalled it from eclipse.

After eclipse restart it was as easy to configure a new glassfish server as it is seen in many blogs, articles and youtube video-s.

Hope to help You!