# Can't install glassfish server -EJB 3.1- on eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, ejb-3.1, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno

I am facing problem with server adapter of glassfish.  Whenever I download the adapter I can't use it as I cannot see it in the wizard.

I download it using "download additional server adapter", but even when it is successfully downloaded, I still do not have choice to work with glassfish as its adapter doesn't show up on the screen.

can any one help?

[image]

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538433/how-to-install-the-glassfish-3-server-adapter-with-eclipse-helios-3-6) to solve your problem....

Comment: Hi Raj Inevitable, I tried to download it form "download additional server adapter" and eclipse restarted but the adapter didn't appear i tried marketplaces and as well the adapter didn't appear .

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution ,

First I am using windows 7 ,64 bit

So when i used JRE 1.6 for 64 bit and i run the eclipse using "run as administrator" , the adapter downloaded and appeared in the wizard .

Thanks