# How to add server-specific resources xml file in Eclipse IDE

Tags: jakarta-ee

Happy New Year To Everyone!

I'm developing a web application project which is targeted to deploy, run on glassfish server. I just wonder how i can (any option available) add glassfish-resources.xml file to my project in Eclipse, please don't tell me to create xml file then rename to glassfish-resources.xml, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a GlassFish server to your eclipse project? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3331367/1817029

Comment: Of course yes I can build and run it without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I've come up with solution by creating xml file with glassfish dtd file resided within glassfish installed directory.